# Creating docx/doc From Custom Xml Java Using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, wordml

I have a custom XML which i have to convert into Microsoft Word Doc/Docx. There are many Java APIs like **Apache POI, docx4j** but i couldn't find any support for creating a word document using XSLT.

Docx4j definitely supports for conversion of docx to xml but what about the way around?

I googled and found [WordML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Word_XML_Format_example)

So i thought of using XSLT to first convert my custom xml to WordML format and then later on convert WordML to doc/docx.

```
     Custom XML----> WordML ------> Docx/Doc
```

My questions are :

- how would i convert WordML to docx/doc (an open source method)
- is it possible to achieve toc linking in WordML

Kindly guide me through if am doing it correctly or suggest a way to do it. Thanks.